# Inserting search term within "No results behavior"

Tags: 8, search, views

Within the 'NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR' section of Views in Drupal 8 how do I output the search term along with some custom text using the "Unfiltered text" option?

My desired output is "No results found for ***search term***, please..."

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can use template_preprocess_views_view

```
 function template_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $variables['view_total_count'] = $view->total_rows;

  if ($view->total_rows === 0) {
    $exposed_input = $view->getExposedInput();
    $search_term = $exposed_input['your search input'];
    $variables['empty'] = 'No results found for'.$search_term.', please ...';
  }
}
```

then in your twig template, you print the empty variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use JS.

Put a placeholder in place of "search term", maybe `<span id="search-term">search term</span>`, so that it still functional when JS is disabled.

Then store the search term in a variable, let's call it `var searchTerm`, and replace text by `document.getElementById("search-term") = searchTerm`.

Now all we got to do is store the search term.

- If the search term is in URL, follow [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/) to extract it.
- If it isn't, please provide more detail and I'll update my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be fairly old, but I will post the solution here.
You can use the D8 port of [search_api_spellcheck](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_spellcheck), here - 
https://github.com/nuvoleweb/search_api_spellcheck. It is not official release, but works well.